# How to implement facebook like reaction pop up animation in android?

Tags: android, facebook, animation

I know how to show popup. But i'm in need to show the popup with animation like facebook like option. And also i want to implement same animation when selecting reactions icon in popup same like facebook like option like the below image. could you please suggest me any idea to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has made its own library to implement this animation. This animation includes image rendering.

Now they have published that library for every fellow developer named [KeyFrame](https://code.facebook.com/posts/354469174916519/keyframes-delivering-scalable-high-quality-animations-to-mobile-clients/).

Add their dependency file.

```
compile 'com.facebook.keyframes:keyframes:1.0'
```

> You can [download the sample](https://github.com/facebookincubator/Keyframes) and explore the ideas.

I hope this will help you.